# Can an Eldritch Knight Attack Twice With Green Flame Blade and War Magic?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, fighter, action-economy, eldritch-knight

An 8th-level Eldritch Knight has a sword.

The **War Magic** class ability says:

> When you use your action to cast a cantrip, you can make one weapon attack as a bonus action

And the cantrip **Green Flame Blade** says:

> You brandish the weapon used in the spell's casting and make a melee attack with it against one creature within 5 feet of you

So I think that means there are 2 sword attacks in total for that turn.

One attack is a bonus action, and one is a side effect of the cantrip. In addition to that are the flame effects of the cantrip as well.

(The 2 attacks are not related to the **Extra Attack** Fighter class ability, which requires taking the **Attack** action, which is not being done here.)

Is the above information correct?

Comment: I have closed your question as a duplicate because I believe it has effectively been asked before. This isn't a bad thing, duplicates actually *help* people find answers because not everybody will ask the same thing in the same way. If you feel the questions I've linked do *not* answer your question, feel free to edit your question or drop a comment explaining why. Your question can always be reopened